# how to fix problem of boxes generated by pdf2image while converting pdf to images.?

Tags: python

I'm trying to convert pdf to images using pdf2image but getting problem of extra generated boxes.
This is my input pdf file screenshot

[this in input file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTbgP.jpg)

```
from pdf2image import convert_from_path

images = convert_from_path('input_pdf.pdf',output_folder=r'C:\Users\Baith')

images[0].save('output.jpg')
```

after executing above code got this output
[output_file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4SsFL.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Since `pdf2image` is only a thin wrapper around `pdftoppm`, itself part of poppler, I would advise trying different parameters with the CLI tools to see it a specific combination works.

As for `pdf2image` itself, you might want to try `use_cropbox=True` and see if it still add lines.

Feel free to open an issue directly of the repository, if you can provide a sample PDF I would be happy to assist with the issue.